# solr set relevancy score in solrconfig

Tags: solr

Im using solr 4.4 ,I want to search by relevancy for exact match words .I have 10 fields ,i used

copy fields to achieve this.And pretty much its working fine.

Im having problem with the exact match results should be higher the order.

Also how i can set score?

### schema.xml

```
 <field name="field8" type="text_search" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="description" type="text_search" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="keywords" type="text_search" indexed="true" stored="true"/>


 <copyField source="field8" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="description" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="keywords" dest="text"/>
```

### solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
<!-- Query settings -->
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>

        <str name="qf">
          field8 description keyword ^10.0
       </str> 
       <str name="df">text</str>
       <str name="mm">100%</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>
     ........
      ........

    ........
```

Comment: Any inputs please?

Comment: Im sorry any pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

### Phrase Fields *pf*

> Once the list of matching documents has been identified using the fq
>   and qf parameters, the pf parameter can be used to "boost" the score
>   of documents in cases where all of the terms in the q parameter appear
>   in close proximity.

For Example if you search for **Apache Solr Lucene** by setting **pf** to the **title**

```
q=Apache Solr Lucen
& qf=title name
& pf=title

<!--Debug-->

<str name="parsedquery_toString">
+((name:apache | title:apache) (name:solr | title:solr) (name:lucene | title:lucene)) (title:"apache solr lucene")
</str>
```

Now If you look at the debug response.It is searching for the single Keyword but also searching it as phrase. So it boost all the search results which have the search String as phrase.

**P.S :- Again pf will only impact boost score not the search results.**